# Is it possible to detect if the cellular network is available in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have created an app that can send text message on a click of a button but strange problem is that when there no coverage the app force closes or sends in no information. so I would like check if there is any cellular coverage if so I am OK with sending SMS or else please try  again!

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Google is your friend: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: This is for check internet connectivity not for cellular connectivity.

Comment: @user1443051 could you post the logcat output of the force close?

Comment: I will be able to put logcat output only when I have no coverage. Which is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by "lack of coverage", no connectivity, you can check this out:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO

check:EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY

If you are talking about signal strength then.... you can also use this as a reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html